# Which .NET based BPM (Business Process Management) software recommended?

Tags: esb, jbpm, bpmn, business-process-management

I need to recommend an open source business process management BPM software engine to work with.

Can anyone suggest such a BPM software to use?

Thanks for you time.

Comment: @Dear Hadi Sharifi, Would you say your result ? We need to BPMS engine which has WorkFlow Engine,Form Builder and report and it is important that we can develop our fully customize pages on this BPMS frame work

Comment: Have a look at https://dwkit.com/, a .NET-based open source BPM solution. It allows you to model, automate and execute mission-critical business processes, whatever industry you’re operating in.

Answer (score 8):

I checked several month ago but I didn't find any good opensource BPMS written for the .net platform.

Fortunatelly, nowdays most BPMS implement an HTTP API which could be accessed from a .net program, and many of them are provided as a cloud service.

I know best java based BPMS where, depending on your needs, you could check [Bonita](http://www.bonitasoft.com/), [jBPM](http://www.jbpm.org/) (which embed a BRMS tool too) or [Activiti](http://activiti.org/). Some exist in other language but I have no feedback on them.

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

After lot of search I found Skelta company who is provided excellent infrastructure in BPMS and engines that be added .NET platfoem to develop customize software

check it out 
http://www.skelta.com/products/bpm/features/ms-office-integration.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The Eclipse Process Manager "Stardust" (http://www.eclipse.org/stardust/) is a mature Java open source BPMS. Its commercial version is used in several products and projects in combination with .NET.

Relevant from this perspective:

- browser-based process modeler
- web service APIs, SOAP and REST
- User interface mashup feature to include .NET UIs in workflows
- Amazon Web Service Stardust image available (http://wiki.eclipse.org/Stardust/Knowledge_Base/Getting_Started/RTE_on_AWS)
- commerical SaaS offering